# Regular Expressions and DFA

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

Where is the difference between these two regular expressions? 
A.(000) * (01)(01) *
B.0(000) * 1(01) *
And which of these to produces the DFA on the picture?[image]

Comment: Are you missing kleene stars?

Comment: The first bracket (000) made a compulsion that either you will have 3 zeros all together or none followed by (01) in second case we will have a single one 1 after 0..

Comment: The picture producees both $0(000)^*1(01)^*$ and $(000)^*(01)(01)^*$

Comment: Both? Guess the 2nd not. Consider 00001.

Comment: The automaton in the picture is not a DFA since it contains an $\varepsilon$-transition.

Comment: @Wuestenfux $00001$ is accepted by the automaton...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (for the first part): the product is associative on languages.

Next, compare $(000)^*0$ and $0(000)^*$.